# Integral inequality for a concave function

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered an inequality of integrals for concave functions when I was reading a paper. The statement is as follows.

Suppose $g$ is a non-negative strictly concave function, $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$, $a<b<c, b>\frac{a+c}{2}$, then $$2(c-b)\int_{a+c-b}^{b}g(x)dx>(2b-a-c)\left[\int_{a}^{a+c-b}g(x)dx+\int_{b}^{c}g(x)dx\right]$$

The paper just said this inequality holds for strictly concave function, I attempted to prove it by Jensen's inequality but failed. I would like to know whether it holds, and how to prove it if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true. BTW, non-negativity of $g$ is not necessary: for $g(x)=1,$ both sides are equal (direct computation), so if the inequality is true for $g(x),$ it's also true for $g(x)-\mu.$ LHS and RHS are also equal for $g(x)=x$ (direct computation, again) and thus for any function $l(x)=\lambda\,x+\mu$. Now choose $l$ so that $l(a+c-b)=g(a+c-b$ and $l(b)=g(b).$ Then, $g(x)>l(x)$ for $x\in(a+c-b,b)$ by strict concavity, and $g(x)<l(x)$ for $x<a+c-b$ and for $x>b$ (one can show that formally, but drawing a picture with the concave graph of $g$ and the secant through the points $(a+c-b,g(a+c-b))$ and $(b,g(b))$ will be convincing enough) and the inequality follows.